# How do I call a function with the following completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I call a function with the following signature?

```
func purchaseSubscription(productId: String, completion:  @escaping  (Bool, String, String) -> Void) {
```

is it

```
InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription("test") {
     processPurchase()
}
```

Comment: `.purchaseSubscription("test") { flag, x, y in` where `flag` is the `Bool` and `x`, `y` your strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be multiple forms to call the method.

**1.** Define the parameters when calling the `closure`, u.e.

```
InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "test") {(x, y, z) in
    print(x, y, z)
    processPurchase()
}
```

**2.** You can use the shorthand form (`$0, $1` etc.) for the parameters in the `closure` while calling it, i.e.

```
InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "test") {
    print($0, $1, $2)
    processPurchase()
}
```

The above 2 are same. Just that in first one you're giving the parameter names and in the second one you're using the shorthand for those parameters.

**3.** In case you're not using any parameters that you're getting in the `closure`, mark them with underscore(`_`) like so,

```
InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "test") {(_, _, _) in
    processPurchase()
}
```

You can use any of the other forms depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The completion handler requires three input parameters. You can ignore the parameters but must be explicit about it. Furthermore the signature indicates this is a member function, while you seem to be calling the function on the type (class, struct, enum...). So the correct way would be:

```
let inAppHandler = InAppHandler()
inAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "test") { _, _, _ in 
    processPurchase()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a your call :

```
InAppHandler().purchaseSubscription(productId: "anyStringData") { (boolCheck, result1, result2) in
            print(result1)
        }
```

And this is your defination :

```
 func purchaseSubscription(productId: String, completion:  @escaping  (Bool, String, String) -> Void) {
    completionResult(true,"Data1", "Data2")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need to use:

```
InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "test") { (boolVal1, stringVal, boolVal2) in
    processPurchase()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call should be like this

```
 InAppHandler.purchaseSubscription(productId: "YOUR_PRODUCT_ID_STRING") { (boolValue, firstString, secondString) in

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using any of the closure params it is recommended to use `_`

```
  purchaseSubscription(productId: "Id") { _, _, _ in
            processPurchase()
     }
```

It is good to check the closure param before you do processPurchase()

```
      purchaseSubscription(productId: "Id") { success, _, _ in
         if success {
               processPurchase()
          }
       }
```